# Webpack 4 basic React js hello world fails with "Module parse failed: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**Update:**

Code pushed to `https://github.com/gsouvik/react_spa_experiment`

**Initial Post:**

I know there are hundreds of threads out there, some had typos in webpack config, some used the loaders in a wrong way, some got it solved, some still open. But after numerous tries I still cannot get this working, a simple "Hello World" using Webpack 4, React js.

**What I did**

I was following this video tutorial line by line:
[React & Webpack 4 from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyxI-6C2u4&t=926s)

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my_react_experiment_2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Basic react with webpack ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Souvik Ghosh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

**My webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.export = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/templates/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**My .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

**My directory structure**

[image]

**Expected behaviour**

I fire up the dev server `npm run dev`. Expected to see my shiny new React js page saying "My first React Webpack project" (from the component /components/App.js)

**Actual Behavior**

> ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | import App from "./components/App";
>   | 
>   ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
>   | //ReactDOM.render('Hello User ', document.getElementById('root'));
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src main[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhUsM.png)

If required I can share the codebase via a git repo. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the repo please ?

Comment: You can view my webpack config if you want to update. https://github.com/meetzaveri/react-doughnut/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: Perhaps you need resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve("./src"),
            path.resolve("./node_modules")
        ],
        extensions: [".js"]
    }

Comment: @MeetZaveri I've updated the original post with the git repo. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with typo in your webpack config file.

You have module.export which is not correct. It should be module.exports

Working example

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/templates/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time and answering. I changed my webpack config to match the one given in your answer but unfortunately it did not fix the issue. I've updated the original post with a git repo. You may clone it on your local and try it to see if it runs successfully. `npm install` and then `npm run dev`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Amazing, that fixed my issue. How could I miss that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even I missed to find that. NP :) Kindly accept and upvote my answer if it helps you resolve your issue.